# Django-filter : filtering using function with a request attribute

Tags: django, django-filter

I'm building a website with Django and I have a little problem with filtering. I have a model `User` which has an attribute `location` and I want the user to be able to search for other users near its own location. I have a function `distance(location1, location2)` computing the distance between two locations. I need user A to search for all users B for which distance(locationA, locationB) is below a value choosen by A. I need to get locationA from the request and this, combined with the use of a function inside the filter, makes things a little bit complicated for a beginer like me. Here is what I have tried so far :

```
import django_filters

class LocationFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    distance = django_filters.NumberFilter(
        field_name='location', method='distance_filter', label='...',
        widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [SOME ATTRIBUTES]

    def distance_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(self__location.distance(request__user__location)__lte = value)
```

Currently, I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. I think I'm misusing the Filter.method of django-filter but the lack of documentation on the internet (other than basic examples) makes it difficult to understand what I'm doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance !

EDIT :

models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models 

class User(models.Model):
    location = models.PointField(blank = True, null = True)
```

Comment: Can you add the full exception message to see where you have invalid syntax

Comment: actually this is where error occure `queryset.filter(location.distance(request__user__location)__lte = value)` - this totaly incorrect. Can you show the models?

Comment: @Charnel thanks for your reponse. Yes it's where the error occurs, I know it's incorrect but I don't understand how to fix it. It's the first time I'm using a custom filtering method and I have difficulties to filter about the value of a function. I have added the model in the post. Actually, this a simplified example because, in my real project, there are a certain number of relationships between the models so I simplify it for a readability purpose

Comment: @Charnel here is a little summary of what I don't understand : 1) Is ```request__user__location``` the correct way to access the attribute for user A ? 2) Where am I supposed to use the ```distance``` function ? 3) How can I get the value the user is entering ?

Comment: (1) - no, the correct way is dot notation `request.user.location`, what you're trying to do is a query filter but it could not get info out of the model fields scope; (2) I'm not much aver of Geo Django but I guess you need to search for anyone close to the user by (first) defining the location within user by using value (that's a distance, right?), (second) use this location in `qs.filter(location__lte=distance)`. (3) it's passed in `value` variable to a method.

Comment: @Charnel so you are saying I cannot use the function ```distance``` inside the query ? With your solution, I need to first define the range of location which are within a certain distance from the user A and then search for every user B located within this range of location. But it's impossible to define this "range of location". Regardless of any GeoDjango considerations, there should be a way to filter a queryset by searching for every object whose value through a function is below a certain number, like ```all obj such as f(obj) < x``` I'm sure there exists something like this in Django

Comment: Yes, you can't use distance inside the query (and that's why you get syntax error). And well, there is a method to [apply function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Func) but it's still could not be used in a way you want.

Comment: So there is no way to do what I want with Django ?

Comment: I'd rather say - there is no way to combine python functions with Django queries.

Comment: Alright thanks for your help !

Comment: I still have a question, I've found a code on the internet that solves the problem ```location2 = self.user.location, 
        return queryset.filter(location__distance_lte(location2, D(m = value)))``` but I got a ```NameError : name 'location__distance_lte' is not defined```. How can I acces the field on which I'm doing the filtering inside the method ? I've also tried with ```name__distance_lte``` in case the name argument correspond to the attribute on which we filter but I got the same error.

Comment: `location__distance_lte` is a method. Did you forgot imports? - `from django.contrib.gis.geos import *` and `from django.contrib.gis.measure import D`

Comment: No I didn't forget the imports. Maybe it's not the right way to access the attribute on which I filter ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to impossible to do what you ask. Queryset filtering is an abstraction which generates an SQL query to send do the database. The database returns the results of executing that query. The database does not have access to your Python context.

So you would need to express your distance function in SQL.

If you are using PostgreSQL I believe this  may be built in (GeoGIS) but that would be at the expense of making your Django app database-specific.

It probably is possible to encode a simple distance function using [`F` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) and [database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/). Consult the Django documentation. (Deep water warning). The alternative is to fetch all possible candidates from the database with a simple filter, and then further filter the results in Python with a complex algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def distance_filter(self, queryset, name, value):
    return queryset.filter(location.distance(request__user__location)__lte = value)
```

Which 'location' are you reaching up there? maybe self.location? I'm confused sorry.

Comment: Yes this is self.location, I forgot to add the self before location, it's now corrected